# How to post javascript code using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript I supposed to send javascript code to php using post method. But When I do returning nothing.

Below is script,

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-113285660-1"></script>

<script>

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

  gtag('js', new Date());



  gtag('config', 'UA-113285660-1');

</script>
```

How to post above script in textarea using php.

Comment: You really need to show us your attempt. Posting that from a textarea is no different from posting anything else from a textarea. If that's not what you're asking, then please clarify the question. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape some dangerous chars. For example with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: @Mohakumar - Are you actually gonna accept this answer this time? You have asked 13 question here on SO now but you have never accepted any answer on any of them.